# Running sudo rfcomm watch hci0 during startup

Tags: bluetooth

To connect to the RPi3 through the Bluetooth Terminal App, I have to run this command first:

```
sudo rfcomm watch hci0
```

How to execute this command automatically during startup of the Rpi?

I found this link,
[Serial Bluetooth Communication](https://pirobotblog.wordpress.com/2016/12/22/serial-bluetooth-communication/)

It does help me connect without running the command after reboot. But Once the device is disconnected, I'm not able to reconnect.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you should find some help on the Raspberry Pi forum with this link: [Raspberry Pi Forum - Run a command on start up.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=14588)

Comment: tl;dr; the link you have given. How is that command started at boot up? And why do you can't reconnect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit your `/etc/rc.local file` and add

```
sudo rfcomm watch hci0
```

if it does not work try putting the command inside a script then make the script executeable. then run the script from `rc.local` like so...

```
sudo nano startfile.sh
```

and put in contents

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo rfcomm watch hci0
```

Press `Ctrl+X` then `Y` to save and Enter to exit

then make it executeable

```
chmod +x startfile.sh
```

finally in the `rc.local` just put in the file name

```
startfile.sh
```

Should work...little rusty on the details but it goes something like that.

Comment: Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.

Comment: adding `sudo rfcomm watch hci0 &` to `/etc/rc.local file` worked just fine! 